# Emacs Yasnippet install

Tags: emacs, code-snippets, yasnippet

trying to install yasnippet for emacs 23 from https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet

Firstly I attempted the quick install but the `yasnippet-bundle.el` for the 'quick' install doesn't seem to be in the repository?

Secondly I attempted the full install.

When trying to do the full install I get the following error:

```
[yas] Check your `yas/snippet-dirs': ~/.emacs.d/snippets is not a directory
```

I have downloaded the latest bundle `joaotavora-yasnippet-e53c41d/` and unpacked in into `.emacs.d/plugins/`

the addition to my `.emacs' is:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path
              "~/.emacs.d/plugins/joaotavora-yasnippet-e53c41d")
(require 'yasnippet) ;; not yasnippet-bundle
(yas/initialize)
(yas/load-directory "~/.emacs.d/plugins/joaotavora-yasnippet-e53c41d/snippets")
```

Basically, the install instructions seem to have become out of sync with the latest src. Does anyone know how to install it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize `yas/root-directory`. Here is how I setup yasnippet

```
(require 'yasnippet "~/emacs/addons/yasnippet.el")
(yas/initialize)
(setq yas/root-directory "~/emacs/snippets")
(yas/load-directory yas/root-directory)
```

Comment: many thanks, I was following the install instructions from the github page, I should have read the install instructions within the download bundle README - these were correct. All working now...